# How to capture a string between parentheses?

Tags: string, lua, string-matching, lua-patterns

```
str = "fa, (captured)[asd] asf, 31"

for word in str:gmatch("\(%a+\)") do
    print(word) 
end
```

Hi! I want to capture a word between parentheses.

My Code should print "captured" string.

> ```
> lua: /home/casey/Desktop/test.lua:3: invalid escape sequence near '\('
> ```

And i got this syntax error.

Of course, I can just find position of parentheses and use string.sub function

But I prefer simple code.

Also, brackets gave me a similar error.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

The escape character in Lua patterns is `%`, not `\`. So use this:

```
word=str:match("%((%a+)%)")
```

If you only need one match, there is no need for a `gmatch` loop.

To capture the string in square brackets, use a similar pattern:

```
word=str:match("%[(%a+)%]")
```

If the captured string is not entirely composed of letters, use `.-` instead of `%a+`.

Answer (score 6):

lhf's answer likely gives you what you need, but I'd like to mention one more option that I feel is underused and may work for you as well. One issue with using `%((%a+)%)` is that it doesn't work for nested parentheses: if you apply it to something like "(text(more)text)", you'll get "more" even though you *may* expect "text(more)text". Note that you can't fix it by asking to match to the first closing parenthesis (`%(([^%)]+)%)`) as it will give you "text(more".

However, you can use [`%bxy` pattern item](http://www.lua.org/manual/5.2/manual.html#6.4.1), which balances `x` and `y` occurrences and will return `(text(more)text)` in this case (you'd need to use something like `(%b())` to capture it). Again, this may be overkill for your case, but useful to keep in mind and may help someone else who comes across this problem.

Comment: Thank you for additional info. and your Lua IDE is awesome!